# Get HTML component from which button was pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the HTML component that contains the button which has been clicked with jQuery? After a button is clicked I need to get the **invite** object that corresponds to the clicked button and send a post request to a given link.

```
{% if invites %}
    {% for invite in invites %}
        <p>Your invites:</p>
        <div class="row">
            <label style="display: block">Invite from {{ invite.initiator }} to join his conference!</label>
            <button type="button" id="ButtonId">Accept invite</button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('#ButtonId').on('click',function(){
            !$(this).hasClass('ButtonClicked') ? addClass('ButtonClicked') : '';
            $('#ButtonId').val('Done');
            var data = {

            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/send_invite/' + /*the username*/,
                data: JSON.stringify(data , null, '\t'),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function() {
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "HTML component" is what the button is wrapped in ? If so, In order to get the element that contains the button that is being clicked (the "parent" of the button) you can do something like this:

```
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){
    var buttonParent = $(this).parent();
    // do your stuff..
});
```

For getting the "invite object" you can attach a data attribute to the accept-invite button, this data attribute will contain a value that you will use to fetch the correct object, for an example:

```
<button type="button" id="inviteAcceptBtn" data-object-id="123">Accept invite</button>
```

Then you can get that "object-id" with simple jQuery:

```
$('#inviteAcceptBtn').on('click',function(){
    var objectId = $(this).data('object-id');
    // do your stuff..
});
```

There are probably a handful of other methods, as there are many techniques to do this.

Hope it helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

Set the the username as one of the button's attributes.

*assuming invite.initiator is the username that you intend to send*

```
<button type="button" id="ButtonId" username={{invite.initiator}}>Accept invite</button>
```

In the javascript code you can access that element easily using `attr` method on `this`

```
url: '/api/send_invite/' + $( this ).attr("username"),
```

Answer (score 0):

@sudomakeinstall2 : It should be better to add the data as a data-attrbute so :

```
<button type="button" id="ButtonId" username={{invite.initiator}}>Accept invite</button>
```

becomes

```
<button type="button" id="ButtonId" data-username="{{invite.initiator}}">Accept invite</button>
```